# Instagram business profile information if not connected to a facebook page

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram

We are trying to pull information out from instagram business user trough graph api. The business user is not connected to a facebook page.

It seems that this thing is possible on apps like Later and several other social media management tools

On the end we would like to display some insights like reach, impression ect.

Comment: The access it via Graph API, the account needs to be connected to a Facebook page, because that is how the authentication parts is implemented - there is no separate way for an IG user to login in to your app and grant it the necessary permissions, so it needs the connection to the page first of all. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/overview#authentication

Comment: Hello! Did you find the solution for this, since I also have similar use case.